# Why does $1 \leq \sup \limits_{0\leq t \leq 1}( C|B_t|)$ P -as where $B$ is the standard B.M for some $C>0$ does not hold?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

> Why does  $1 \leq C\sup \limits_{0\leq t \leq 1}( |B_t|)$ P -as where $B$ is the standard B.M for some $C>0$ does not hold ?

I am trying to show by contradiction that the Burkholder-Gundy inequalities do not extend to random times. In order to prove this I need to show the above .

I am not so sure how to proceed. I know that since Brownian motion is almost surely continuous , $|B_t|$ is almost surely bounded on the interval $[0,1]$ and hence $\sup \limits_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |B_t| \leq C'$ almost surely. I can't argue why however high $C$ is there is always a set of non-zero measure such that on that set we have

Comment: For every $x>0$, the hitting time $T_x=\inf\{t\geqslant0\mid|B_t|\geqslant x\}$ is unbounded in the sense that $P(T_x\gt t)\ne0$ for every $t$. Since $C\sup\limits_{t\leqslant 1}|B_t|\lt1$ on the event $\{T_{1/(2C)}>1\}$, this shows that $P(C\sup\limits_{t\leqslant 1}|B_t|\geqslant1)\ne1$ for every $C$.

Comment: Note that by a similar reasoning, "$\sup \limits_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |B_t| \leq C'$ almost surely" is wrong for every $C'$, contrarily to what you seem to be asserting.

Comment: @Did My bad, I was sloppy , I wanted to say that for almost every $\omega$ there exists a $C(\omega )$ such that  $\sup \limits_{0 \leq t \leq 1}|B_t(\omega)| \leq C(\omega)$.

Comment: @Did But why is it true that for every $x >0$, the hitting time $T_x=\inf \{t \geq 0 \vert |B_t| \geq x\} $ is unbounded in the sense that $P(T_x >t) \noteq 0$ for every t

Comment: C(omega): If this is your question, note that you are asking to show that the supremum random variable is almost surely finite--which is a direct consequence of the almost sure continuity of the Brownian paths. Finiteness of T_x: What are your sources about Brownian motion, already?

Comment: @Did I didnt get your last question: Finiteness of $ T_x$: What are your sources about Brownian motion, already? What do you mean by sources?. I studied brownian motion in my course on financial mathematics if that's what you mean. What i do not understand why the statement you made in your first comment claiming that the hitting time $T_x$ is unbounded ? Can you please explain that